# Where is the fusebox on the map Kino der Toten?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, cod-black-ops-zombies

In COD: Black Ops Zombies, where is the fusebox and how do you get there in Kino der Toten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the green star symbols, the switch is in the north theater and located next to the  teleporter.

[image]